# Does scale invariance imply massless or continuous mass distribution?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, mass, representation-theory, scale-invariance

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rvert}\newcommand{\scp}[2]{\langle #1 \vert #2 \rangle}$
In his 2008 slides
([PDF](http://www.phys.nctu.edu.tw/file/970522.pdf)), Tzu-Chiang Yuan mentions the following on p. 21:

> Suppose $P^2\ket{p}=m^2\ket{p}$ with $\scp{p}{p}=1$ and fixed $m^2$. Then,
>
> $$[P^2,D]=P^{\mu}[P_{\mu},D]+[P^{\mu},D]P_{\mu}=2\mathrm{i}P^2$$
>   $$\bra{p}[P^2,D]\ket{p}=2\mathrm{i}\bra{p}P^2\ket{p} =2\mathrm{i}m^2$$
>   $$\bra{p}[P^2,D]\ket{p}=\bra{p}(m^2D-Dm^2)\ket{p}=0$$
>   implies $m=0$
>
> Or continuous mass spectrum since:
>   $$e^{\mathrm{i}sD}P^2e^{-\mathrm{i}sD}=e^{2s}P^2$$
>   Where $D=x_{\mu}P^{\mu}$ and $P^{\mu}$ up there is $\mathrm{i}P^{\mu}$

My questions are, first why would we assume that $P^2\ket{p}=m^2\ket{p}$ and how did his analysis make him conclude that $m=0$?

Lastly he did not define $s$ in the continuous spectrum scenario and also I did not see why would $e^{isD}P^2e^{-isD}=e^{2s}P^2$ imply continous spectrum, I would appreciate if some one can explain those points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $p^2 = m^2$ is the *definition* (up to a minus sign) of the mass of a momentum eigenstate.
2. He derived that the same quantity (the expectation value of $[P^2,D]$ w.r.t. $\lvert p\rangle$) equals $0$ and $2\mathrm{i}m^2$, so $m^2 = 0$.
3. The $s$ is the *scale parameter* of the scale transformation induced by $D$, and it is any real number, so, starting from a given state with mass value $p^2 = m^2$, we can produce *any* positive mass value by the scale transformation, so $P^2 \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{2s}P^2$ under a scale transformation implies that the spectrum is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, I now got 1) and 2). 

Concerning 3), what is $D$ here? Is it any operator or is it some specific operator that I should be aware of? Also, I understand now that how did scale transformation imply spectrum continuity, but I still do not see how $e^{isD}P^2e^{−isD}$ would equal $e^{2s}P^{2}$ anyway? Shouldn't it be, mathematically speaking, equal to $P^2$? Where did the $e^{2s}$ in $e^{2s}P^{2}$ come from?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: Uh...the $D$ is the $D$ from your OP, i.e. the dilation/scale operator. And, no, mathematically speaking, you have to use (a variant of) the [BCH formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma) for commuting operator exponentials.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: Scale invariance means *by definition* that the theory is *invariant* under scale transformations generated by $D$. We are looking at the commutator because it is the transformation of $P^2$ under $D$. There's a caveat because $D$ is not the right operator to generate quantum transformations since it is not Hermitian - there should appear a normal ordering constant somewhere, and its absence is suspicious. I would be careful to take the contents of that PDF at face value, there are subtleties hidden. I would advise reading a proper paper on the topic and *not* some slides.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe this should be instead some $U=e^{i\epsilon D}$ so it could work out..